# Open-source PHP Accounting/General Ledger Implementation

Tags: php, open-source, accounting

I'm looking for any open-source accounting module that I can include in my Symfony project. I was thinking of writing my own & releasing a plugin, but then I came across 2 solutions:

- http://arias.sourceforge.net/
- http://frontaccounting.net/

Please answer on the lines of...

1. Choosing one of the above, your experience, community support
2. Other alternatives

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Accounting is a broad field. Can you specify your requirements some more?

Comment: I need an API to post accounting entries (GL, Journal), create Chart of Accounts, get Trial Balance, and possible statements

Comment: @Prasad now when it has been quite some time when you asked the question, can u plz share what you used? I am also looking for such a package/library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my take:
- Arias is not being maintained any more, but I didn't invest much energy
- FA on the other hand is very comprehensive; don't go by the name, its a basic ERP. You will love to play-around at the demo link. It uses pure PHP, and no framework. One can take a lot of inspiration from here, and use it readily if the license allows.

Sadly, there is nothing for symfony and I will try to contribute.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's an option to outsource the accounting but if any of the following have APIs then they could possibly solve your problem:

- http://billmonk.com
- http://buxfer.com
- http://mint.com
- http://wesabe.com

I believe they let you create arbitrary (sub)accounts and issue IOUs and transfers between the accounts, like for keep track of who owes who what among a group of people.

Comment: oh thanks dreeves, but by accounting I meant an implementation of General Ledger.. plus this would be super costly!

Comment: Yeah, just thought it was worth mentioning just in case (or for others searching for answers to similar questions).  As to cost, my understanding is that with a single account you can create arbitrary sub-accounts.  At least for some of the above group accounting sites.